British Mini-Series from the Nineties about Northern Ireland and members of the I.R.A
There was a mini-series in the early to mid 90's that was centered around the British Army and the IRA, it was a very good production but I missed the last couple of episodes. I'm hoping that someone out there can give me the name of it. I cant remember the names of any of the cast, but i do know there were a couple of well known actors. It was told from both the British and the IRA's perspective.
The first episode started with the story of an older man who's last name probably was "Apple" and I'm pretty sure he was either an informant or a double agent.

Can you remember any of the actors? There's been a fair few TV series and movies set in the Troubles with big name actors, e.g. The Crying Game, In the Name of the Father and The Boxer.

No I can picture some faces but just can't put names to them. And it's a mini-series not a Movie.

Sounds like the mini-series Children of the North from 1991. From IMDb:

One subplot features an undercover army officer trying to infiltrate an IRA cell while posing as a double agent and another subplot features a split in the IRA which leads to the provisionals liquidating the dissidents before it leads to a destructive feud in the republican movement

There's a character there called Arthur Apple played by Michael Gough (the butler from the 1989-1997 Batman movies).

Thanks Walt that's definitely the answer, much appreciated.
